# mailboxer error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

I want to make my user model act as messageable.

I added

```
gem 'mailboxer', github: 'mailboxer/mailboxer'
```

in the gem file.

I added

```
acts_as_messageable
```

in the user model.

I assiged

```
u1 = User.first

u2 = User.find_by(id: 2)
```

when I write the following command in console:

```
u1.send_message u2, "body", "subject"
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for # Mailboxer::Message:0x00000007392c70>
```

Does anybody knows what can be the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Does your `User` model have an `email` field?

Comment: u1.email
=> "example@example.org"

Comment: Did you setup mailboxer correctly by following the `README` guide (eg. `rails g mailboxer:install`, setting up methods for `name` and `email`)?

Comment: In user.rb: def mailboxer_email(object)
    #return the model's email here
     return object.email
  end

Comment: user has user.name property

Comment: I have executed the command rails g mailboxer:install